# matplotlib change extent in quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an imshow plot, showing clouds, and an a superimposed quiver plot, showing cloud motion vectors. This plot is now shown in pixels, but I'd like to show it in kilometer, the size of the cloud scene. I can change the extent in imshow, but than the quiver plot doesn't fit anymore.

Do you have any suggestions how to do that? Any help would be appreciated!

Merry Christmas

Here is my code:

```
# size I want to be shown in the plot (in kilometer)
size = 9.750

# -> extent[0, size, 0, size]


# arrays used in plot (pixel size)

im_current = np.array((275,275))  
xdis_mean = np.array((275,275))
ydis_mean = np.array((275,275))


# settings for the quiver plot

sliceNr=20  # every x pixel will be shown
sy,sx =np.shape(im_current) 
x=np.arange(sx)[::sliceNr]
y=np.arange(sy)[::sliceNr]


# colormap for the quiver plot
M = sqrt(pow(xdis_mean[::sliceNr,::sliceNr], 2) + pow(ydis_mean[::sliceNr,::sliceNr], 2))



fig=plt.figure()

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
cax=ax.imshow(im_current,origin='lower', cmap=cmap,vmin=0,vmax=1,norm=norm)

setp(plt.Axes.get_xticklabels(plt.gca()), fontsize=10)
setp(plt.Axes.get_yticklabels(plt.gca()), fontsize=10)


title('image at t=0 \n with mean displacement vector field')

xlabel('area size [pixel]',fontsize=9)
ylabel('area size [pixel]',fontsize=9)

# get axes from subplot to adjust colorbar to these axes
divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
cax1 = divider.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="4%")

cbar1=plt.colorbar(cax,cax=cax1,cmap=cmap,boundaries=bounds,ticks=[0,1],use_gridspec=True)
cbar1.ax.set_yticklabels(['0','1'],fontsize=10)


v=ax.quiver(x,y,xdis_mean[::sliceNr,::sliceNr],ydis_mean[::sliceNr,::sliceNr],M, units='xy',angles='xy',scale=1,scale_units='xy',cmap='autumn')

cax2 = divider.append_axes("bottom", "5%", pad="9%")
cbar2=plt.colorbar(v,cax=cax2,orientation='horizontal',use_gridspec=True)
for t in cbar2.ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_fontsize(10)

plt.tight_layout()

show()
```

To illustrate it, here's the figure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way to go about doing this: you can either re-scale the (x,y) data of the quiver, or set the label formatters.

option A goes something like this:

```
x,y = x*km_per_pixel + km_offset_x, y*km_per_pixel + km_offset_y
im = ax.imshow(...,exent=lims_in_km)
q = ax.quiver(x,y,...)
```

option B goes something like this:

```
q = ax.quiver(..)
im = ax.imshow(...) # exactly like you had before
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(
        lambda x,i: '%.2f' % (x * km_per_pixel + km_offset_x)))
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(
        lambda x,i: '%.2f' % (x * km_per_pixel + km_ofset_y)))
```

You should tweak the formatting string to be what ever you like.  If you want more control over *where* the ticks are look in to `Locator`s. (The documentation for all of these classes is at [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html))

Comment: Thank you very much! I chosed option A and without '+km_offset_x' it worked! Actually very easy...don't why I had such a problem finding an answer. So thanks and happy new year!

Comment: I took option B now, because then I can use units='xy' in ax.quiver, which make it look sooo much better than units='dots', which I used with option A. So thanks for these two options!